# Problem with installing EmoPY requirements

Tags: python

I tried to install EmoPy NN to my computer (here is the link https://github.com/thoughtworksarts/EmoPy). I used both OS Ubuntu and Windows. The problem is in library versions. [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIK1N.png). I get an error while installing file requirements.txt.

So my next step was to install all of dependencies on my own, counting them one by one. But then another error occured, which said, that some methods are not valid.

As cloning from github was unsuccessful, I decided to try to use pip installer. Unfortunately, the same problem with the conflict of versions occured.

So are there any possible solutions or that NN is too old and too difficult to be installed?

P.S. I use python 3.6.6. as documentation requires

Answer (score 0):

I have simple instruction with installed Anaconda (conda env python 3.6), cloned from Git an emopy.

1. pip install -r requirements.txt
   there is a little feature with dependency version(one library needs old version scipy 1.0.0, other needs 1.0.1)
2. write pip install scikit-image==0.16.2
3. if you start script from examples\fernmodel_example.py(emotions are determined by photo here exactly, in others some weird figures, it's not our needs, if i'm not mistaken), it will get several errors in saving.py file from keras library - to delete .decode("utf-8") one by one, while doesn't work.
   You can fix other exampeles, of course, but it doesn't make sense yet.